# If a C++ function's return type is T, does returning a local variable of type T effectively make the variable an rvalue?

Tags: c++, c++11

When I compile this with GCC:

```
struct A
  {
    A();
    A(const A &);
    A(A &&) = delete;
  };

void ugh(A);

A bar()
  {
    A a;
    ugh(a);
    return(a);
  }
```

I get the error:

```
x.cpp: In function ‘A bar()’:
x.cpp:14:13: error: use of deleted function ‘A::A(A&&)’
     return(a);
             ^
x.cpp:5:5: note: declared here
     A(A &&) = delete;
     ^
```

In practical terms, it does make sense to consider a in the return statement to be an rvalue (as it's about to be destroyed).  But doesn't the Standard require rvalues to be anonymous?

Also, even if it's permitted to use the move constructor in this case, why is it required?  Why can't the compiler use the copy constructor, since the move constructor is not available?

The answers to his previous question, [Does returning a local object require move semantics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29164188/does-returning-a-local-object-require-move-semantics) , mostly address mine, but don't touch on how a named variable can become an rvalue with no call std::move().

EDIT:  These two links explain why gcc's behavior is correct, and shed light on why the Standard requires this behavior:
[Why do C++11-deleted functions participate in overload resolution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14085620/why-do-c11-deleted-functions-participate-in-overload-resolution)
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/return

Comment: There is a rule that whenever NRVO could apply, the compiler must at least move, rather than copy (it may still be elided).

Comment: @TavianBarnes You should write an answer.

Comment: And whether return value optimization can or cannot be used, it doesn't change the rules and the requirements of the language.

Comment: Note that [gcc](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/VURQNseWZmy7E7aY) and [clang](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/2UJYUS9rDIbJjEGr) disagree on this.

Comment: You should never delete the move constructor explicitly for a copyable class like this. You should let the compiler select the copy constructor.

Comment: Esp the 2nd answer is relevant.