# Virtual destructor with default implementation

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++14, virtual-destructor

Let's see this code:

```
struct S {
  virtual ~S() = default;
};
```

First question is: is this OK according to the standard? I cannot find the relevant syntax on [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/destructor). Second question is will this prohibit the compiler from generating copy/move constructor/assignment operator? Reference to the standard would be appreciated.

Comment: [This destructor reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/destructor) might be a good start.

Comment: 1.  Yes.  2.  See the chart in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15181645/576911

Comment: @HowardHinnant Thanks for the link. So `= default` does count as user-defined and prohibits the compiler from generating special members.

Comment: @Lingxi:  Yes, but said a little more precisely, it counts as user-*declared* and prohibits the compiler from generating the move members.  The copy members are still generated with a user-declared destructor, but that behavior is deprecated.  To avoid depending on deprecated behavior, declare the copy members if you declare the destructor.