# Why *this can work as a & type?

Tags: c++, qt

```
class Cell : public QTableWidgetItem
{
public:
    Cell();

    QTableWidgetItem *clone() const;
...
}
```

Above is the class definition in a Qt program.
Below is the rest part.

```
QTableWidgetItem *Cell::clone() const
{
    return new Cell(*this);
}
```

My question is about the last sentence, if I change it to like:

```
return new Cell(this);
```

Then Qt will give error message:
[image]

Why? I understand that `this` is a pointer, and cannot be the argument.
But `*this` could be a `&` type?

Comment: Because `*this*` is a `Cell`. Passing a `Cell` as an actual parameter to a function that takes a `Cell&` as its formal parameter is perfectly fine in C++ and will pass that parameter by reference. It's analogous to how you'd initialize a reference variable.

Comment: Thank you for this good explaination!

Comment: @Michael Your excellent comment missed the "Your Answer" box by a few inches. Better luck next time!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you haven't defined a copy constructor for your class, the compiler generates one for you with the following signature: `Cell(const Cell&)` (read more here: [Conditions for automatic generation of default/copy/move ctor and copy/move assignment operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4943958/conditions-for-automatic-generation-of-default-ctor-copy-ctor-and-default-assi)). When you try to invoke `Cell(this)`, the compiler attempts to find `Cell(Cell*)` among the various `Cell` constructors - obviously none matches. `Cell(*this)` matches the auto-generated copy constructor `Cell(const Cell&)` since it expects a reference to an object of type `Cell` as a parameter (not a pointer to it), and `*this` dereferences the pointer so the actual object can be passed by reference. As far as the calling syntax considered, the invokation of `Cell(*this)` can be resolved by the compiler as passing by reference or as passing by value. Since in your case the copy constructor receives the parameter by reference (due to the `&` in the signature), the compiler will resolve the `Cell(*this)` as pass-by-reference (actually it must be by reference, but that's another story). Read more about the subject here: [What's the difference between passing by reference vs. passing by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373419/whats-the-difference-between-passing-by-reference-vs-passing-by-value)