# Is a move constructor created by default?

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, move-semantics

I know that a copy constructor is always created by default even if I don't explicitly create one. Is the same true for a move constructor? Let's assume a have a very simple class:

```
class SimpleClass
{

public:
    SimpleClass(int value) :
            member(value)
    {}

    int member;

};
```

Do I explicitly need to write `SimpleClass(SimpleClass &&other) default` to create the default move constructor or not?

Comment: Look at [conditions-for-automatic-generation-of-default-ctor-copy-ctor-and-default-assignment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4943958/conditions-for-automatic-generation-of-default-ctor-copy-ctor-and-default-assi)

Comment: Watch out for Visual Studio versions prior to 2015 they did not create move constructor by default.

Answer (score 1):

Like the copy constructor the move construction is available by default. Check the reference docu [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor)

Comment: Except, that if you declare a copy constructor, destructor or assignment operator, move operations won't be generated.