# why I can pass a reference to derived class object to base class constructor without any compiling error?

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor, copy-constructor, default-constructor

In class A, I do not define any constructor that takes parameters. In class B, which is a derived class of class A, I define a copy constructor and it passes a reference of B to the constructor of A. It is so weird to see this code does pass the compiling and the output is below. Could someone explain it a little bit?

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class A{
  public:
    A(){ std::cout<<"A constructor called"<<std::endl;};
    ~A(){};
};

class B:private A{
  public:
    B(){std::cout<<"B default constructor called"<<std::endl;};

    B(const B& b): A(b){std::cout<<"B constructor called"<<std::endl;};
};

int main()
{
  B b{};
  B b2{b};
  return 0;
}
```

output

```
 A constructor called
 B default constructor called
 B constructor called
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Conditions for automatic generation of default/copy/move ctor and copy/move assignment operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4943958/conditions-for-automatic-generation-of-default-copy-move-ctor-and-copy-move-assi)

Comment: I don't think this question is so bad. It's well-written, with example code, and the output is given.

Answer (score 3):

`A(b)` calls the *copy constructor* in `A`, which has been provided by the compiler for you.

See for yourself by writing

```
A(const A& a) {std::cout << "A copy constructor called\n";}
```

in class `A`. This is all perfectly well defined C++.

Comment: @WubinOuyang: There's no harm in answering your own question.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out five minutes after I asked. It is actually calling the copy constructor of A which is created by compilers