# How does one argument constructor work?

Tags: c++

I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>


class TestClass {

private:
    int var1, var2;

public:
    TestClass()
        :var1(0), var2(0)
    {}

    TestClass(int x)

    {
        std::cout << "\nOne argument constructor\n";    
    }

    void showData()
    {
        std::cout << "var1 = " << var1 << std::endl;
        std::cout << "var2 = " << var2 << std::endl;
    }

};

int main()
{
    TestClass obj;
    obj.showData();

    obj = 3;
    obj.showData();


    return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT:

[image: output]

---

My questions:

1 - Why am i able to call a one argument constructor in a statement where the object isn't declared?
2 - Why has the value of **var1** and **var2** changed after calling one argument constructor?

---

I ran the code on VS community edition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [many cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4943958/conditions-for-automatic-generation-of-default-copy-move-ctor-and-copy-move-assi) including yours, the compiler is able to automatically generate (among others) an assignment operator of the form `TestClass& operator=(const TestClass&)`. Since `TestClass` is implicitly constructible from a single integer, `obj = 3` is resolved as `obj = TestClass(3)`.

This also explains why `var1` and `var2` change: the compiler constructs a `TestClass` object that leaves them uninitialized, then these uninitialized values are copied to your object. If you assign a specific value to `var1` and `var2` (such as 1), you'll get that value after the copy assignment.

Answer (score 2):

A one-argument constructor that is not marked `explicit` can be used for an implicit conversion sequence.

In the code `obj = 3;`, it could be satisfied by implicit conversion of `int` to `TestClass`.   Your one-argument constructor can be used for this purpose; the code behaves the same as `obj = TestClass(3);`.

Your program causes undefined behaviour by attempting to display uninitialized variables. The one-argument constructor should initialize `var1` and `var2`.