# operator + need Move Constructors

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2019

I cannot compile the attached project because I deleted the move constructors.

Is this the expected behavior? Why does the compiler need the move constructors if it won't use it?

windows-visual studio 2015 14.0.25431.01 update3

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

class poo {
public:
  poo() = default;
  poo(poo&&) = delete; //deleted function
  virtual ~poo() = default;

  poo operator +(const poo &a) const {
    poo to_return;
    to_return._s += a._s;
    return to_return;
    //moveconstructors.cpp(14): error C2280: 'poo::poo(poo &&)': attempting to reference a deleted function
  }
private:
  std::string _s;
};

int main(int, char **) {
  poo a;
  return 0;
}
```

EDIT 1:
the same result happens after adding "poo (const poo &) = default;"

EDIT 2:
the same result happens with windows-visual studio 2019 16.1.0 preview 2.0

EDIT 3:
the same result happens after adding/modifying

```
  poo(const std::string &s) : _s(s) {
  }
  poo operator +(const poo& a) const {
    return poo(_s + a._s);
  }
```

EDIT 4: it works fine with vs2019 and /std:c++17

Comment: By `poo(poo&&) = delete;` you also disabled copy operations, so you cannot copy / move `poo` instances.

Comment: Also, operator + should be a non-member free function.

Comment: @NeilButterworth, nah, it doesn't have to. It is sometimes more convenient, but it is not a requirement.

Comment: `virtual ~poo() = default; //deleted function` this reminds me of the all-time `i++; // decrement i`

Comment: Also, NRVO is not guaranteed by the standard.

Comment: @rafix07 y u answer in cmomentz

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: not pre C++17, and OP is using VS 2015 which doesn't have that version of the std

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Actually I don't think NRVO is guaranteed even in C++20. RVO is though.

Comment: @AndyG Oh yeah you're right

Comment: Re: Your edits, are you using `/std:c++17` in msvc 19? [It works fine here](https://godbolt.org/z/2vyL7W)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A elision optimisation is permitted here (NRVO) but the object must still be semantically copyable/moveable; [by deleting the move constructor, you also deleted the copy constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4944131/560648), so neither operation is valid and the program is ill-formed.

You can add the copy ctor back:

```
poo(const poo&) = default;
```

*(And, even if you were using C++17, [its guaranteed elision doesn't apply to lvalues](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38043447/560648).)*

Answer (score 8):

```
poo(poo&&) = delete;
```

This line disables the move constructor, yes, but it *also* deletes the copy constructor.

From class.copy.ctor:

> If the class definition does not explicitly declare a copy constructor, a non-explicit one is declared *implicitly*.
>   If the class definition declares a move constructor or move assignment operator, the implicitly declared copy
>   constructor is defined as deleted;.

Now, all this wouldn't be a big deal if [named return value optimization (NRVO)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision) was guaranteed by the standard, because the compiler could see that your `operator+` has a single return of a local variable. In that case, we wouldn't need copy or move constructors; the `poo` instance would be created and passed to the fn by reference ("under the hood").

Note that in C++17 you can use guaranteed copy elision (RVO) to get around this:

```
poo(std::string s) : _s(std::move(s)){}

poo operator +(const poo &a) const {
  return poo(_s + a._s);
}
```

[Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Hg3LbXmpth39maRZ)

However, even in C++20, *named* return value optimization is not yet guaranteed. An implementation is permitted to use a move operation instead.

[class.copy.elision] states:

> In the following copy-initialization contexts, a move operation might be used instead of a copy operation: 
>       - If the *expression* in a **return** statement is a (possibly parenthesized) *id-expression* that names an object with automatic storage duration declared in in the body or *parameter-declaration-clause* of the
>   innermost enclosing function or *lambda-expression*