# Why is there more destructor calls than constructor calls

Tags: c++, constructor, destructor

I was testing out the following code and what confused me is that there is more destructor calls than constructor calls:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A {
    A() { std::cout << 1; }
    A(int) { std::cout << 7; }
    ~A() { std::cout << 5; }
};

struct B {
    B() { std::cout << 2; }
    B(int) { std::cout << 9; }
    ~B() {std::cout << 3;}
};

struct C {
    B b;
    A a1;
    A a2;
    C() : a1(3){
        b = 3;
        a2 = 7;
    }
};

int main(){
    C c;
    return 0;
}
```

The output is like follows:

```
B()  A(int) A() B(int) ~B() A(int) ~A() ~A() ~A() ~B() 
 2     7     1    9      3     7     5    5    5    3
```

My guess is that on the lines b = 3 and a2 = 7, 3 and 7 must be implicitly converted to B and A and when they get copied into b and a2, they get destroyed.

Is this correct or is something else going on here?

Comment: In the output provided by you, I see the same numbers of calls to constructors and destructors: *3* call pairs for `A` and *2* call pairs for `B`. What am I missing?

Comment: For some reason I thought that the A(int) constructor was a copy constructor and not a basic constructor. I figured it out now..

Comment: You would have had better results if you output the value of `this` instead of those numbers.  You would quickly see that some of the objects being destroyed were not properly tracked by your code.

Comment: Now that I've read all these answers I feel kind of dumb for asking, because it's clear as day to me now what is going on here. I was for some reason thinking that the A(int) is copying the integer value into b/a2, where it is actually constructing a temporary object that is then getting copy assigned into b/a2. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 7):

You are not logging the *copy constructors* and *copy assignment operators*, eg:

```cpp
struct A {
    A() { ... }
    A(int) { ... }
    A(const A&) { ... } // <-- add this
    ~A() { ... }
    A& operator=(const A&) { ...; return *this; } // <-- add this
};

struct B {
    B() { ... }
    B(int) { ... }
    B(const B&) { ... } // <-- add this
    ~B() { ... }
    B& operator=(const B&) { ...; return *this; } // <-- add this
};
```

But, if you actually count the outputs you have shown, you will see that you ARE seeing matching constructors and destructors. You have 3 `A` constructor calls and 3 `~A` destructor calls. And you have 2 `B` constructor calls, and 2 `~B` destructor calls.

```
B()         C::b
A(int)      C::a1
A()         C::a2
B(int)      temp
B=          temp -> C::b
~B()        temp
A(int)      temp
A=          temp -> C::a2
~A()        temp
~A()        C::a2
~A()        C::a1
~B()        C::b
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/9j6FSQ)

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/64da8fe376f01e45 It's copy assignment, not copy constructors that are the issue

Comment: Sidenote: I really thought that the user defined destructor would delete the default-generated copy constructor and assignments. I'm shocked that this wasn't the case.

Comment: @MooingDuck - Why on earth would it?

Comment: @Dzamba you ARE seeing the temp objects being destructed. Count the outputs. You have 3 `A` objects being constructed and destructed, and 2 `B` objects being constructed and destructed.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica: I assumed because a custom destructor almost always means RAII, which means non-trivial copies. Instead, it only checks for copy/move ctors+assignment. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4943958/conditions-for-automatic-generation-of-default-copy-move-ctor-and-copy-move-assi