# Does the destructor of the baseclass prevent creation of move constructors in subclasses?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-constructor

As per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4944131/13611002), which says that[emphasise mine]:

> The move assignment operator is auto-generated if there is no user-declared copy constructor, copy assignment operator or **destructor**, and if the generated move assignment operator is valid (e.g. if it wouldn't need to assign constant members) (§12.8/21).

Does an inherited destructor count? I mean, say I've got a base class with an empty virtual destructor. Does it prevent creation of move constructors in subclasses?

Answer (score 1):

The compiler will generate the move constructors for you:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <utility>

struct Foo {
    virtual ~Foo() {}
};

struct Bar : public Foo {
    Bar() : pi(new int(5)) {};

    std::unique_ptr<int> pi;
};

int main()
{
    Bar b;
    std::cout << b.pi.get() << std::endl;
    Bar c = std::move(b);
    std::cout << b.pi.get() << std::endl;
    std::cout << c.pi.get() << std::endl;
}
```

which (on a given run), output:

```
0x1b65e70
0
0x1b65e70
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lY09a8MwEIZ3/YqDLjbBgQylYDsZOvQvdCzyWTUH@nDlU9IS3J9e9ZyCkw4dqkHinnveVziO1YCY8x15tKk30FKYOBrtDurKnHEhftySxGSJBSmxEzI8hQBnBXKOFDlpC5@CihLOs5qbVXvUEWoYU2cJbzKCRZUFFd6cgDwX9@WSleSyn7iv6@TpLZmXkWMrwkHk5lItAzhNvijV2gZdcw1iSAxtC912pO1gWL6S6bIyvrfNGkLY/2AXjqboyv92/DLxL3PO@QtfrR6mXAne42aze8jVs7ZWbvPOUS9vjCF@Aw)

If the compiler had not generated the move constructor, `c` could not have been constructed (since by using `std::unique_ptr` as a member, implicit copy is not allowed), and clearly the ownership over the pointer was transferred properly. The code was compiled under GCC with warnings maxed out in `-std=c++17` mode, with no issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can tell if a member function is user-declared by looking at the class definition. If you see the function, then it is user-declared.

For example:

```cpp
class Derived : public Base {
   ~Derived() = default; // <-- see this? user-declared destructor
};
```

In contrast to:

```cpp
class Derived : public Base {
   // <-- see a destructor here? No. So not a user-declared destructor
};
```

The compiler generates the same destructor body in both cases, but the former example has a user-declared destructor, while the latter has an auto-generated destructor. The user-declared destructor is compiler-generated in this case, but it is generated at the user's request, so it is not **auto**-generated.

For "user-declared", it does not matter what's going on in the base class. If you see the destructor listed, as in the first example, then the compiler will not auto-generate move assignment or move construction. If you do not see the destructor listed, as in the second example, then the other criteria for auto-generation need to be checked.

The base class' influence on which members are auto-generated is restricted to the "is valid" criterion.

Comment: The most important phrase in the answer is "it does not matter what's going on in the base class".  The base class may or may not have a move ctor, but if it has a copy ctor available, the derived will use it to move itself.