# Default destructor bad for move semantics (performance)?

Tags: c++, performance, c++17, destructor

After listening to various **CppCon** YT talks on modern C++ tips and best-practices I'm sorta confused -
Specifically, is this construct **bad** for performance by disabling the compiler's ability to use move semantics for `CDerived`?

```
class CDerived : public CBase   {

public:

           CDerived();
  virtual ~CDerived() = default;   // <== THIS - Bad, even when using default?
    
    
  virtual void  DoStuff();
};
```

I suppose in contrast to other questions linked in comments this comes down to

- Does the `default` destructor count as auto-generated or user-declared destructor (given it's created by the compiler).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Conditions for automatic generation of default/copy/move ctor and copy/move assignment operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4943958/conditions-for-automatic-generation-of-default-copy-move-ctor-and-copy-move-assi)

Comment: It's hard to answer within the context you provide. What are "some YT talks"? Please post links or at least explain your objections. Did you measure or profile anything?

Comment: It has happened that "some YT talks" are inaccurate. Perhaps the `virtual` is the problem, and not the `default`?

Comment: Adding the destructor removes the auto-generated move constructor. So, yes, objects of this class cannot be moved. When you remove the destructor, it can be moved. When specifying the destructor, you also have to specify move constructor and move assignment operator.

Comment: @Friedrich Sorry, should have been more specific - I'd have to search through recent CPPCON talks for hours to find the relevant bits; but basically it sounds like modern C++ guidelines suggest not to provide dummy (empty) destructors in derived classes. Unsure if this applies to `default` as well.

Comment: @mch ..does it apply regardless of providing an empty destructor or having the compiler synthesize one via `default`?

Comment: @mch Question is does `default` fall under **auto-generated** or **user-declared**

Comment: when you write `~CDerived = default;`, it is user-declared, because you declared it to be default.

Comment: @mch Hmm... *"The destructor is not user-provided (meaning, it is either implicitly declared, or explicitly defined as defaulted on its first declaration)"*, https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/destructor

Comment: and it is explicitly defined as defaulted in your case.

Comment: why would you declare this destructor at all? I mean in the presence of public inheritance it does matter how the destructor of `CBase` is delcared/defined, and if the destructor of `CDerived` does nothing anyhow, why bother to declare it?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number ..cleaning up old legacy code, earlier misconceptions of C++. This is *old* code...

Comment: @ATV `= default` is as *old* as move semantics