# Why does C++ class show 2 constructors after I declared only one constructor?

Tags: c++, constructor

I have the following C++ class:

```
class MyClass
{
private:
    PCWSTR _windowName{};
    PCWSTR _windowTitle{};

public:
    MyClass(PCWSTR wndName, PCWSTR wndTitle)
    {
        this->_windowName = wndName;
        this->_windowTitle = wndTitle;
    }
};
```

When I try to create a variable of this class type, it shows 2 constructors and one of them was not declared by me.

**Constructor declared by me:**
[image]

**And this one?**

[image]

What is this second constructor?

Comment: The second constructor is called a **copy constructor**.  So you can do `MyClass a; MyClass b{a};` to construct a `b`, copied from `a`.

Comment: Note that copy constructors (along with a few other [special member functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_member_functions)) are created for you by the compiler so long as [certain conditions are met](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4943958/4581301).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every class that doesn't have a [copy constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor) declared by the user has one implicitly declared. What you are seeing there is that copy constructor. It will also usually, and in your case as well, be implicitly-defined, so that it copies every member individually, if that is possible.

The IDE is however a bit inconsistent. There should also be an implicitly-declared [move constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor) for your class with the signature `MyClass(MyClass&&)`, which is also usually, and in your case as well, implicitly-declared and -defined to *move* each member individually, if possible, but with some additional conditions applying (e.g. no user-declared destructor). So in total the class has three constructors.

Comment: There's also a bunch of other cases that make the move constructor not generate, but none of those apply here https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor

Comment: @MooingDuck I intentionally didn't mention the conditions under which a move constructor is implicitly-declared, because they are a bit more complicated. The copy constructor is always declared. The implicit declaration with a user-declared destructor is deprecated, but unfortunately I don't think it will ever be removed. Makes forgetting/ignoring the rule-of-zero/three/five much more likely unfortunately.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor 
"The implicitly-declared or defaulted copy constructor for class T is defined as deleted if any of the following conditions are true:
T has non-static data members that cannot be copied...;
T has direct or virtual base class that cannot be copied...;
T has direct or virtual base class or a non-static data member with a deleted or inaccessible destructor;
T is a union-like class...;
T has a data member of rvalue reference type;
T has a user-defined move constructor or move assignment operator...;"

Comment: @MooingDuck Yes, but that's about the definition. It is still declared either way. I tried to clarify my answer without going into the technicalities.

Comment: The new wording is correct, and simple. I like it. +1