# Why isn't named return value optimization working here?

Tags: c++, return-value-optimization

I know that I have deleted the copy constructor, I was assuming that was OK since I was expecting named return value optimization and that direct initialisation would happen. Does the copy constructor need to be declared? If I do I have the problem that a member of the class can't be copied either, so what do I do?

```
class UniqueBufferPointer
{public:
    UniqueBufferPointer() {}
    UniqueBufferPointer(const UniqueBufferPointer& other) = delete;
    UniqueBufferPointer(UniqueBufferPointer&& other) {}
    UniqueBufferPointer& operator=(const UniqueBufferPointer&) = delete;

};


struct GFXAPIImage
{
    GFXAPIImage() {}

    UniqueBufferPointer handle;
    GFXAPIImage(const GFXAPIImage&) = delete;
    //GFXAPIImage(const GFXAPIImage& other) = default; // If I use this instead of the compiler complaining that it can't access the copy constructor of this class, it complains it can't access the copy constructor of UniqueBufferPointer.

};


GFXAPIImage func()
{
    GFXAPIImage f;
    return f; //GFXAPIImage(const GFXAPIImage&) cannot be referenced, it is a deleted function
}


int main()
{

    GFXAPIImage f = func();
}
```

I'm on Visual STudio and compiling with /O2 optimization flag.

Edit: Also if I declare a move constructor for GFXAPIImage it compiles. Does this mean it uses the move constructor? Why? It's an l-value it should have no business moving it.

Comment: Unrelated: that `public:` placement is awful.

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio are you using? Do you define a specific C++ Standard or do you use the default?

Comment: @YSC Version 17.2.3 and std:c++latest

Comment: _It's an l-value it should have no business moving it._ I believe NRVO is an exception to this rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By explicitly deleting `GFXAPIImage`'s copy constructor, you're preventing the compiler from supplying a implicitly-defined default move constructor.

This is a problem, since when you write `return f`, the object `f` needs to be either copied or moved. But without a move constructor, it can't be moved, and with a deleted copy-constructor, it can't be copied. Boom: compiler error.

Note that NVRO is not actually relevant here. What NVRO means is that the compiler is allowed to  optionally elide the call to `GFXAPIImage::GFXAPIImage(GFXAPIImage&&)` when returning a named object from a function. But this is only an *optimization*. You still need `GFXAPIImage::GFXAPIImage(GFXAPIImage&&)` to exist in the first place for the code to be well formed.

To fix your code, you can simply remove the explicitly deleted copy constructor from `GFXAPIImage`. This will enable the compiler to supply an implicitly-defined default move constructor, which will make `GFXAPIImage` move-able again. Optionally, you could instead define your own move constructor, or request the compiler to supply a default move constructor even with the deleted copy constructor with `= default`.

Note that even if you don't explicitly deleted the copy constructor, it will still be implicitly deleted. So you don't lose any safety by omitting the explicit deletion.

See also [Conditions for automatic generation of default/copy/move ctor and copy/move assignment operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4943958/11082165)

```
struct GFXAPIImage
{
    GFXAPIImage() {}

    UniqueBufferPointer handle;
    // no explicitly deleted copy constructor

};


GFXAPIImage func()
{
    GFXAPIImage f;
    return f; //  OKAY, calls move constructor
}

int main()
{

    GFXAPIImage f = func();
    // GFXAPIImage g = f; // would fail due to GFXAPIImage(const GFXAPIImage&) being implicitly deleted
}
```

Comment: I've just realised that adding an explicit move constructor and defaulting it makes it compile. Why is this necessary? Is it calling the move constructor?

Comment: @Zebrafish It's a "safety feature". If your class defines a copy constructor, there's a very good chance the the default move constructor would break it. Think about a custom `std::vector` that only defines a copy constructor. Bad things would happen if it got an implicitly-defined default move constructor that just copied the storage pointer.

Comment: @Zebrafish I edited by answer to further clarify why the move constructor is necessary here

Answer (score 5):

Named return value optimisation is a non-mandatory copy elision. This means the object returned must have an accessible, non-deleted copy or move constructor.

Citing [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision#Non-mandatory_copy.2Fmove_.28since_C.2B.2B11.29_elision):

> #### Non-mandatory copy/move (since C++11) elision
>
> Under the following circumstances, the compilers are permitted, but not required to omit the copy and move (since C++11) construction of class objects even if the copy/move (since C++11) constructor and the destructor have observable side-effects. The objects are constructed directly into the storage where they would otherwise be copied/moved to. This is an optimization: even when it takes place and **the copy/move (since C++11) constructor is not called, it still must be present and accessible (as if no optimization happened at all), otherwise the program is ill-formed**:
>
> - **In a return statement, when the operand is the name of a non-volatile object with automatic storage duration**, which isn't a function parameter or a catch clause parameter, and which is of the same class type (ignoring cv-qualification) as the function return type. **This variant of copy elision is known as NRVO, "named return value optimization."**

Citing the Standard [`[class.copy.elision]/1`](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.copy.elision#1):

> When certain criteria are met, an implementation **is allowed** to omit the copy/move construction [...]
>
> - in a return statement in a function with a class return type, when the expression is the name of a non-volatile object with automatic storage duration [...]