# constructor taking 0 parameters yet we can still pass an object reference in C++?

Tags: c++, constructor

I have a class `Counter` where there's only the default constructor which of course takes 0 parameters. However, inside one of the member functions, a temporary `Counter` object is created and it takes an argument that is the object itself `*this`. Below is my commented code.

```cpp
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
    
class Counter {
public:
    Counter();// notice that there's only the default constructor.
    ~Counter() {}
    int GetItsVal() const { return itsVal; } 
    void SetItsVal(int x) { itsVal = x; }
    void Increment() { ++itsVal; }
    const Counter& operator++ ();
    const Counter operator++ (int); // currently learning overloading postfix and prefix. not sure if this has to do anything with my question,.
private:
    int itsVal;
};
Counter::Counter():
    itsVal(0) 
{};

// I understand everything in overloading the prefix,.
const Counter& Counter::operator++() {
    ++itsVal;
    return *this;
}


const Counter Counter::operator++(int theFlag) {
    /*
     we are making a Counter object and it is taking an argument? 
     Is it perhaps because a default constructor can take a reference to an object as a parameter only?
    */
    Counter temp(*this); 
    ++itsVal;
    return temp;
}
int main() {
    // learning postfix and prefix. not important for the question.
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The compiler automatically generates a copy constructor for you if you don't.  rules for this are found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4943958/conditions-for-automatic-generation-of-default-copy-move-ctor-and-copy-move-assi

Comment: Similarly, if there's no destructor one will be created for you. So your destructor isn't needed.

Comment: @Issac Howard Pay attention to that the unary increment operator should return a non-constant reference:  Counter& operator++ (); because for fundamental types expressions like that ++++a are valid.

Comment: Please have a look at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three

Comment: @Issac Howard And the semicolon at the end of the destructor definition Counter::Counter():
    itsVal(0) 
{}; us redundant.

Comment: @NathanOliver I am sorry but I don't get it. Do you mean that we can pass a reference to the object itself as a parameter to the constructor?

Comment: @IssacHoward No, what I'm saying is that since you didn't provide a copy constructor, a constructor with the form of `class_name(const class_name&)`, the compiler automatically creates one for your class for you, unless you have declared a move operation.

Comment: @NathanOliver oh now I get it, sorry I forgot the copy constructor was something that was created automatically. Thank you,.

Comment: imho its a pity that there is no canonical q&a for this. I remember some very handy table to explain when which special members are provided by the compiler, but dont find the link atm

Comment: its findable =) https://safecpp.com/RuleOfDesDeMovA.html

Comment: The original talk by Howard Hinnant was given at the 2014 edition of ACCU Conference. The [slides from that talk](https://accu.org/conf-docs/PDFs_2014/Howard_Hinnant_Accu_2014.pdf) are posted at ACCU.org. In 2016, Hinnant reprised his talk for Inside Bloomberg: [video on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vLinb2fgkHk), [slides at GitHub](https://howardhinnant.github.io/bloomberg_2016.pdf).