# Compiler generated methods

Tags: c++

When declaring a class/struct/union the compiler will generate the default methods [(rule of three)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3734247/what-are-all-the-member-functions-created-by-compiler-for-a-class-does-that-hap). This also will happen when `= default`'ing these methods.

How do the default methods exactly look like?

Comment: It isn't that simple. If you `default`, say, the copy constructor, you don't get a default constructor any more. There are also rules concerning move constructors and move assignment operators.

Answer (score 0):

For example let consider the default constructor. According to the C++ Standard

> An implicitly-declared default constructor is an inline public member
>   of its class.

and

> The implicitly-defined default constructor performs the set of
>   initializations of the class that would be performed by a user-written
>   default constructor for that class with no ctor-initializer (12.6.2)
>   and an empty compound-statement.

So it looks like

```
struct A
{
   A() {}
};
```

except that it is not explicitly declared and defined.

About copy constructor you can read at my personal forum

http://cpp.forum24.ru/?1-1-0-00000021-000-0-0-1388485669

Though it is written in Russian but you can translate it for example using google service translate.

Answer (score 0):

For each of these methods, the compiler defines default inline methods that call the default methods of each attribute of the object. (so a pointer won't be initialized neither any built-in type).

Answer (score 0):

Those method will do the minimum necessary to initialize the class.

Default construtor - do nothing with simple members but call the constructors of more complex members (class/struct) as well as call the ctor of its super class.

Copy constructor will perform a shallow copy (memcpy).