# What compiler will give for us for empty class in C++?

Tags: c++

In one of the interviews, I was asked given an empty class, what compiler gets for you? Can anybody please let me know what compiler will provide for any empty class?

Comment: Do you mean size or something else?  Is an empty class exactly `class empty{};`?

Comment: Which compiler? What happened when you tried it?

Comment: see it yourself at http://gcc.godbolt.org/

Comment: I know the size will be '1' even though it is empty. But the interviewer asked any other things I know

Comment: @kadina What exactly was asked for? Size or something else? You're unclear as can be with the wording of your question!

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is The Rule of Three?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer depends a lot on how the class is used and which version of C++ is involved:

- The class will have non-zero size, so that pointer arithmetic works and the elements of arrays of them will be distinct.

  ```
  assert(sizeof(empty_class_t) != 0)
  ```
- The class will have a default constructor, if you construct any.

  ```
  empty_class_t e;
  ```
- The class will have a default copy constructor, if you copy any.

  ```
  empty_class_t f(e);
  ```
- The class will have a default copy assignment operator, if you assign any.

  ```
  empty_class_t g = f;
  ```
- In C++11, the class will have a default move constructor, if you use it.

  ```
  empty_class_t h(std::move(g));
  ```
- In C++11, the class will have a default move assignment operator, if you use it.

  ```
  empty_class_t j; j = std::move(h);
  ```

I think I've got all the uses right - someone let me know of any booboos, please.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3734247/what-are-all-the-member-functions-created-by-compiler-for-a-class-does-that-hap) for details of when these are generated for classes in general, but basically they are only generated if the compiler can do something sensible **and they are used in your code**; the compiler is not required to fail where one of these default members cannot be generated but is not used.

Comment: Also if anyone knows why markdown isn't syntax highlighting the examples!

Comment: When you have numbered or bullet points you have to double-indent  code under them.