# Constructor being called multiple times

Tags: c++

I wrote the following c++ code trying to understand copy elision in c++.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class B
{
  public:  
  B(int x  ) //default constructor
  {
    cout << "Constructor called" << endl;
  }    

  B(const B &b)  //copy constructor
  {
     cout << "Copy constructor called" << endl;
  } 
};

int main()
{ 

  B ob =5; 
  ob=6;
  ob=7;

  return 0;
}
```

This produces the following output:

```
Constructor called
Constructor called
Constructor called
```

I fail to understand why is the constructor being called thrice with each assignment to object ob.

Comment: The thing about constructor elision is that it's an optimization permitted by the language, and not a requirement of the language. This means it isn't always done (depending on your optimization level, etc.). In particular, usually the compiler won't elide constructor calls if they have side effects (like yours does here).

Comment: Implicit conversions can use constructors. Here, since `int` is implicitly convertible  to `B` with the constructor `B(int)`, that constructor is called in all three lines. The copy-constructor (`B(const B&)`) can also be called on the first line if it weren't for [copy-elision](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision).

Comment: Your first constructor, by the way, is technically called a custom constructor (default constructors can be called with no arguments).

Comment: Side note: `B(int x)` is no default constructor. That is `B()`.

Comment: Side note: You may experiment  `explicit B(int x)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> B ob =5;

This uses the given constructor.

> ob=6;

This uses the given constructor because there is not a `B& operator=(int)` function and `6` must be converted to type `B`. One path to do this is to temporarily construct a `B` and use it in the assignment.

> ob=7;

Same answer as above.

> I fail to understand why is the constructor being called thrice with each assignment

As I stated above you do not have a `B& operator=(int)` function but the compiler is happy to provide a copy assignment operator (i.e., `B& operator=(const B&);`) for you [automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3734247/what-are-all-the-member-functions-created-by-compiler-for-a-class-does-that-hap). The compiler generated assignment operator is being called and it takes a `B` type and all `int` types can be converted to a `B` type (via the constructor you provided).

**Note:** You can disable the implicit conversion by using `explicit` (i.e., `explicit B(int x);`) and I would recommend the use of `explicit` except when implicit conversions are desired.

#### Example

```
#include <iostream>

class B
{
public:
    B(int x) { std::cout << "B ctor\n"; }

    B(const B& b) { std::cout << B copy ctor\n"; }
};

B createB()
{
    B b = 5;
    return b;
}

int main()
{
    B b = createB();

    return 0;
}
```

#### Example Output

Note: Compiled using Visual Studio 2013 (Release)

```
B ctor
```

This shows the copy constructor was elided (i.e., the `B` instance in the `createB` function is triggered but no other constructors).

Comment: Is there a special provision in cpp to create a temporary object and call a 1 parameter constructor (if given explicitly ) in such cases instead of an error saying primitive type int can't be assigned to class object?

Comment: You can prevent implicit conversions by using `explicit` (e.g., `explicit B(int x);`) which causes `B b = 5` to produce a compilation error. I would recommend using `explicit` unless you are wanting implicit conversions.

Answer (score 4):

Each time you assign an instance of the variable `ob` of type `B` an integer value, you are basically constructing a new instance of `B` thus calling the constructor. Think about it, how else would the compiler know how to create an instance of `B` if not through the constructor taking an `int` as parameter?

If you overloaded the assignment operator for your class `B` taking an `int`, it would be called:

```
B& operator=(int rhs)
{
    cout << "Assignment operator" << endl;
}
```

This would result in the first line: `B ob = 5;` to use the constructor, while the two following would use the assignment operator, see for yourself:

```
Constructor called
Assignment operator
Assignment operator
```

http://ideone.com/fAjoA4

If you do not want your constructor taking an `int` to be called upon assignment, you can declare it `explicit` like this:

```
explicit B(int x)
{
    cout << "Constructor called" << endl;
}
```

This would cause a compiler error with your code, since it would no longer be allowed to implicitly construct an instance of `B` from an integer, instead it would have to be done explicitly, like this:

```
B ob(5);
```

On a side note, your constructor taking an `int` as parameter, is not a default constructor, a default constructor is a constructor which can be called with no arguments.

Answer (score 3):

You are not taking the **assignment operator** into account.  Since you have not defined your own `operator=()` implementation, the compiler generates a default `operator=(const B&)` implementation instead. 
Thus, your code is effectively doing the following logic:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class B
{
  public:  
  B(int x) //custom constructor
  {
    cout << "Constructor called" << endl;
  }    

  B(const B &b)  //copy constructor
  {
     cout << "Copy constructor called" << endl;
  } 

  B& operator=(const B &b)  //default assignment operator
  {
     return *this;
  } 
};

int main()
{ 
  B ob(5); 
  ob.operator=(B(6));
  ob.operator=(B(7));

  return 0;
}
```

The compiler-generated `operator=()` operator expects a `B` object as input, but you are passing an `int` value instead.  Since `B` has a non-`explicit` constructor that accepts an `int` as input, the compiler is free to perform an implicit conversion from `int` to `B` using a temporary object.

That is why you are seeing your constructor invoked three times - the two assignments are creating temporary `B` objects.