# C++ Auto Generates Move Constructor With User Declared Destructor?

Tags: c++, destructor, c++14, move-constructor

According to [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3734247/what-are-all-the-member-functions-created-by-compiler-for-a-class-does-that-hap), C++ should *not* automatically generate a move constructor if there is a user declared destructor. Checking this in practice with Clang, however, I see an auto-generated move constructor. The following code prints "is_move_constructible: 1":

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

struct TestClass
{
  ~TestClass()
  {}
};

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
  std::cout << "is_move_constructible: " << std::is_move_constructible<TestClass>::value << std::endl;
}
```

Am I misunderstanding "there is no user-declared destructor" or std::is_move_constructible? I'm compiling with '-std=c++14' and Apple LLVM version 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Types without a move constructor, but with a copy constructor that accepts `const T&` arguments, satisfy `std::is_move_constructible` and implicitly-declared copy constructor has the form `T::T(const T&)`.

If implicitly-declared copy constructor is deleted, `std::is_move_constructible` is not satisfied as below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

struct TestClass
{
  ~TestClass() {}
  TestClass(const TestClass&) = delete;
};

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
  std::cout << "is_move_constructible: " << std::is_move_constructible<TestClass>::value << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For C++11 code, the accepted answer by @Alper is fine. But to make your code future-proof, note that as of Clang 3.7 (no idea which Apple version that corresponds to, sure you can find out), using `-std=c++1z -Wdeprecated` will generate the following

```
warning: definition of implicit copy constructor for 'TestClass' is deprecated because it has a user-declared destructor [-Wdeprecated]
  ~TestClass()
  ^
```

[**Live Example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d0d67f909a52fbaf)

The relevant part of the draft C++1z Standard [**N4567**](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4567.pdf) is

> **12.8 Copying and moving class objects [class.copy]**
>
> 7 If the class definition does not explicitly declare a copy constructor, a
>   non-explicit one is declared implicitly. If the class definition
>   declares a move constructor or move assignment operator, the
>   implicitly declared copy constructor is defined as deleted; otherwise,
>   it is defined as defaulted (8.4). **The latter case is deprecated if the
>   class has** a user-declared copy assignment operator or **a user-declared
>   destructor**.

Deprecated means that a future Standard may stop generating an implicit copy constructor in case of a user-declared destructor. It's best practice to change your code **today** to not rely on deprecated behavior (i.e. in this case, making the copy-behavior of your class explicit).

Comment: My clang version is `clang version 5.0.0-3~16.04.1 (tags/RELEASE_500/final)`. And I use the options `-std=c++1z -Wdeprecated` too, but it doesn't give me any warnings.