# Move operation even if Destructor is defined

Tags: c++

I read this:

> N3337 [class.copy]/9: If the definition of a class X does not explicitly declare a move constructor, one will be implicitly declared as defaulted if and only if
>
> X does not have a user-declared copy constructor,
> X does not have a user-declared copy assignment operator,
> X does not have a user-declared move assignment operator,
> X does not have a user-declared destructor, and
> the move constructor would not be implicitly defined as deleted.
> Declaring the destructor and defining it as default counts as user-declared.

Here: [Does a default virtual destructor prevent compiler-generated move operations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33957037/does-a-default-virtual-destructor-prevent-compiler-generated-move-operations)

However, this code:

```
struct A1 { virtual ~A1() {};  };

struct B1 : public A1 {
    ~B1() override {};  };

struct A2 { virtual ~A2() = default;  };

struct B2 : public A2 {
    ~B2() override = default;  };

struct A_NO_VIRTUAL {
    ~A_NO_VIRTUAL() {};  };

struct B_NO_VIRTUAL : public A_NO_VIRTUAL {
    ~B_NO_VIRTUAL() {};  };


int main() {  std::cout << std::is_nothrow_move_constructible_v<B1> << std::is_nothrow_move_constructible_v<B2> << std::is_nothrow_move_constructible_v<B_NO_VIRTUAL> << std::endl; }
```

prints:
111

See: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5c53057a1a4ce3f4

expected:
000

Why is that?

Comment: "Types without a move constructor, but with a copy constructor that accepts const T& arguments, satisfy std::is_move_constructible. " - https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_move_constructible

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C++ Auto Generates Move Constructor With User Declared Destructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35239552/c-auto-generates-move-constructor-with-user-declared-destructor)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`is_move_constructible` roughly checks whether `MyClass x(std::move(y));` is valid. It can be valid if `MyClass` doesn't have a move constructor, but does have a copy constructor, which is going to be silently used in place of the move constructor.

Declaring a destructor only removes the move operations, but keeps the copy ones (the latter is deprecated).

To test this properly, add a member variable to your class, and log the calls to the member's copy and move constructors.