# No matching Function for a call

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, header-files

I've created very simple C++ project in codeblocks. I have header file (CVector.h), source file (CVector.cpp) and main code (code.cpp). When I try to compile the code I got the following message:

```
CVector.cpp|22|error: no matching function for call to 'CVector::CVector()'|
```

code.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "CVector.h"
using namespace std;

int main () {
CVector vec1(1,2);
CVector vec2 (3,4);
cout << "vec1 data "; vec1.printData();
cout << "vec2 data "; vec2.printData();

cout << "vec1 area: " << vec1.area() << endl;
cout << "vec2 area: " << vec2.area() << endl;

return 0;
}
```

CVector.h

```
#ifndef CVECTOR_H
#define CVECTOR_H


class CVector
{
   int x,y;
   public:
        CVector (int, int);
        int area();
        void printData ();
        CVector operator+ (CVector param );
};

#endif // CVECTOR_H
```

CVector.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "CVector.h"
using namespace std;

CVector::CVector (int a, int b) {
x=a;
y=b;
}

int CVector::area() {return x*y;}

void CVector::printData(){
cout << "X = " << x << ", Y = " << y << endl;
}

CVector CVector::operator+ (CVector param )
{
    CVector temp;
    temp.x=x + param.x;
    temp.y=y + param.y;
    return temp;
}
```

The error is related to the operator overloading function because it compiles without problems when I comment this function.

Comment: The [default constructor is not auto generated when you explicitly declare you're own](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3734247/what-are-all-the-member-functions-created-by-compiler-for-a-class-does-that-hap), as you've done (`CVector(int, int)`).

Comment: Yes I know, I just noticed that I need it in the definition of the operator overloading. Thank you so much

Comment: Edit: ... when you explicitly declare **your** own ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `operator+`, the line

```
CVector temp;
```

needs a default constructor, but you didn't define one.
(If you define a non-default constructor, the compiler will not provide a default one.)

You can either define a default constructor, if you can decide on what suitable default values of the members could be, or you can write

```
CVector CVector::operator+ (CVector param )
{
    CVector temp(x + param.x, y + param.y);
    return temp;
}
```

or even

```
CVector CVector::operator+ (CVector param )
{
    return CVector(x + param.x, y + param.y);
}
```

Comment: Have an upvote, for 1. being first, and 2. showing how to use the existing ctor.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in you `operator +` is this line:

```
CVector temp;
```

This lines creates a default-constructed `CVector`. However, your `CVector` class does not have a default constructor, hence the error. You need to add one to the class:

```
class CVector
{
   int x,y;
   public:
      CVector(); // Added
      //The rest as before
};
```

There are two ways to implement it. One:

```
CVector::CVector() {}
```

This will result in the members `x` and `y` remaining uninitialised.

Two:

```
CVector::CVector() : x(0), y(0) {}
```

This will initialise `x` and `y` to 0.

The second one is safer, the first one is faster. Which one to use depends on your goals for the class.

---

Unrelated, but in your two-parameter constructor, you should use the member initialisation list instead of assignments as well:

```
CVector::CVector(int a, int b) : x(a), y(b) {}
```

It doesn't really matter for primitive types such as `int`, but it's a good habit to grow. It's more efficient for members of a type with a nontrivial default constructor, and is actually nceessary for members of a type *without* a default constructor.