# Conversion From Pointer To NonScalar Object Type?

Tags: c++, pointers, overloading, default-arguments

Can someone explain why the following works, Tried the following code and it works fine.

```
class A { 
public :
    int32_t temp ;
    A ( bool y = false  ) { }
} ;

int main ( int argc, char *argv[] )
{

  A temp ; 
  temp = new A () ;
  temp.temp = 5 ;

  std::cout << " " << temp.temp << std::endl ;
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}               // ----------  end of function main  ----------
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your case. The compiler used an [implicitly defined Copy/Move Assignment operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3734247/what-are-all-the-member-functions-created-by-compiler-for-a-class-does-that-hap). Which first constructs `A` with the pointer using your constructor that takes a `bool`.

---

All pointer types are [implicitly convertible](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion) to `bool` in C++. There are two ways to prevent such nonsense:

- `explicit` constructors
- `deleted` constructors

Thus, you can do this:

```
class A {

  public :
    int32_t temp ;
    explicit A( bool y = false  ) {
    }

    //Additionally
    A(void*) = delete;
};
```

defining a constructor that takes only a `void*` as deleted, will have [overload resolution](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution) rank that constructor higher than the `bool` constructor when you pass a pointer. Since it will be picked by overload resolution whenever you pass a pointer and because it's deleted, the program will be ill-formed.