# C++ primer says that we can use initializer list for "=default" constructors

Tags: c++, constructor, default

```
struct SalesData {

    SalesData() = default;
    SalesData(const string&s) : bookNo(s) {}

    string bookNo;
    unsigned copies_sold = 0;
    double revenue = 0;
};
```

While discussing default constructors, primer says we can use the keyword "=default" to make a constructor default just like code above. That keyword can appear with the declaration inside the class, or with the definition outside the class.
If the compiler can't use in-class initializers, we can use initializer list just like the second constructor.

But what's the format?

First I tried to use initializer list directly:

```
SalesData() = default:bookNo(""), copies_sold(1), revenue(2){};
```

But it can't work, the compiler says there shouldn't be a colon afer "default".

Then I tried to declare the constructor with "=default" in class and define it outside, without using the initializer list:

```
struct SalesData {
    SalesData() = default;
   /*...*/}

SalesData::SalesData() {
    bookNo = "";
    copies_sold + 0;
    revenue = 0;
}
```

The compiler says it's an error of redefinition.
Then I moved the keyword outside, which the primer says is supposed to be ok:

```
struct SalesData {
    SalesData();
   /*...*/}

SalesData::SalesData()=default {
    bookNo = "";
    copies_sold + 0;
    revenue = 0;
}
```

It still failed, the compiler said there should be a semicolon behine the "default".

I've googled for similar questions, but nothing found.

1. How could the "=default" and initializer list work together?
2. How should I use the "=default" outside the class body?

Comment: If you have an initializer list, it is a user defined constructor and not the default version. So just skip the `=default`.

Comment: `=default` is used to specify when you want the compiler to generate a constructor/assignment for you. This implies you cannot have a definition of it. It also only applies to default (we need more words), copy and move constructors and the respective assignments, not a user-defined constructor with an initializer_list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In certain situations the compiler automatically generates special functions like the default ctor for you. `=default` is a way to tell the compiler explicitly to generate the function even in a situation where that would not happen automatically.

The point is: You *either* implement the function yourself as usual *or* you `=default` it. You cannot do both for the same function. The only way to influence what the compiler generates is via default initializers like your `double revenue = 0;`

Compiler generated implementations are available for the default ctor, copy ctor, copy assignment, move ctor, move assignment and destructor. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3734268/6646408) for more details. `SalesData(const string&)` is neither of those, so it cannot be `=default`ed.

Comment: Thanks, now I learn that definition and =default can't work together. However, the C++ primer 5th says, "...Under the new standard, if we want the default behavior, we can ask the compiler to generate the constructor for us by writing =default after the parameter list. **The =default can appear with the declaration inside the class body or on the definition outside the class body**..." So what could the words about declaration and definition mean ?

Comment: @Dardai You can put `=default` in either of those places. It's not using good words though as they are both declarations without `=default`, and definitions with `=default`.  (Also there is a semantic difference, the out-of-line situation does not count as *user-provided*)

Answer (score 3):

If a function is declared `=default`, you cannot provide an initializer list (for a constructor), nor a function body.

Either the book is wrong or you misunderstood what the book is saying.

Comment: Note that the OP is probably referring to aggregate initialization, which is allowed for explicitly defaulted constructors and it does use the initializer list syntax.

Comment: Thanks, now I learn that definition and =default can't work together. However, the C++ primer 5th says, "...Under the new standard, if we want the default behavior, we can ask the compiler to generate the constructor for us by writing =default after the parameter list. **The =default can appear with the declaration inside the class body or on the definition outside the class body**..." So what could the words about declaration and definition mean ?

Comment: @Dardai I think it just meant you can write it inside the class like `SalesData() = default;`, or outside like `SalesData::SalesData() = default;`.

Answer (score 1):

Some additions.

If you do not specify any constructor in your class the compiler generates the *default* constructor. This constructor just initializes all the members with their default (empty) constructor (naturally if that constructor exists otherwise it runs to compilation error).

If you specify a non-default constructor the compiler does not generate the default one automatically. Here you can find some details:

[Conditions for automatic generation of default/copy/move ctor and copy/move assignment operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4943958/conditions-for-automatic-generation-of-default-copy-move-ctor-and-copy-move-assi)

The `=default` keyword means that you *explicitly* ask the compiler to generate the default constructor with default body (also if you already specified another one). This means the *body* of this constructor is created by the compiler not by you. This is the reason why you got compilation error if you tried to define it.

Note that the `=default` keyword can be used also at destructors.