# Should a constructor ever be called on assignment?

Tags: c++

The output of the code below in VS2015 is "constructor".

Shouldn't it fail to compile due to the missing assignment operator?

```
struct A { };

struct B {
    B(){}
    B(const A& a) {
        cout << "constructor" << endl;
    }

    //B& operator=(const A& a) {
    //  cout << "assignment operator" << endl;
    //  return *this;
    //}
};

int main() {
    A a;
    B b;
    b = a;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This will be of use to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3734247/what-are-all-the-member-functions-created-by-compiler-for-a-class-does-that-hap

Comment: But those don't handle any conversion, like from A to B, right?

Comment: Oh I see it now, I thought it was one of those were B was inheriting from A. Apologies. In this case, I think there's something weird going on. This might be a compiler thing.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Yes, when there is a conversion going on, like in your testcase.

You're effectively calling

```
b = B(a);
```

Because `B`'s assignment operator `B& operator=(B const&)` is implicitly declared, it is found during overload resolution. Because your assignment is only one conversion away from being a match (and that's exactly the number of conversions that are allowed to happen), it converts `a` to `B` and then assigns the new temporary `B` to `b`.

Answer (score 14):

Let's consider an analogous example.

```
double a;
int b=5;

a=b;
```

The only thing you can assign to a `double` is another `double`. However, an `int` can be converted to a `double`.

Similarly here, `A` can be converted to `B`, because the constructor to do so exists. And that's what happens.

Comment: Well, you can assign an `int` to a `double`. The defined behaviour of this is that the `int` is implicitly converted to `double` and the result of that conversion replaces the stored value of the `double`.  Maybe it would be better to say "The only thing that can be stored in a `double` variable is a `double` value", or something.

Answer (score 11):

Your code has implicit conversion from `A` to `B`, the `b = a` is compiled as `b = B(a);`. If you want this to be detected as error, you can use [the `explicit` specifier](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit):

```
struct B {
    B(){}
    explicit B(const A& a) {
        std::cout << "constructor" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

Then you should get error, such as [these generated by ideone.com](http://ideone.com/g1Dy0r):

```
prog.cpp: In function 'int main()':
prog.cpp:20:7: error: no match for 'operator=' (operand types are 'B' and 'A')
     b = a;
       ^
prog.cpp:5:8: note: candidate: B& B::operator=(const B&)
 struct B {
        ^
prog.cpp:5:8: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'A' to 'const B&'
prog.cpp:5:8: note: candidate: B& B::operator=(B&&)
prog.cpp:5:8: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'A' to 'B&&'
```

After that, the constructor will never be implicitly called, and if you want to call it, you have to write it explicitly: `b = B(a);`

Comment: Good mention of the `explicit` keyword