# What is exactly the rule of the three regarding to implement one of them CPP

Tags: c++

My teacher teached me, that when im using one of the big three (i.e. copy constructor\default\assignment), so the compiler is not going suplly me the other for free and I have to implement them by myself.
But I tried to implement a constructor like this:

```
A(int a): integer(a){};
```

And I succeed however to do this:

```
A my_first_ob(100);
A my_second_ob(my_first_ob);
```

How it is possible?
Maybe someone can clear me the things here?

Comment: Your teacher told you a non default constructor stops the auto generation of the copy constructor?

Comment: No, the rule of three does not mean that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is The Rule of Three?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)

Comment: I think your teacher meant the destructor instead of the (default) constructor

Comment: @NickyC That is not a correct dupe.  A correct dupe would be: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3734247/what-are-all-the-member-functions-created-by-compiler-for-a-class-does-that-hap

Comment: @NathanOliver Perhaps you are right. Perhaps [What is The Rule of Three](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three) is more an FYI than a dupe.

Answer (score 0):

The constructor you implemented is not a copy constructor or a default constructor, so it has nothing to do with what (you think) your teacher said.

I believe either you or your teacher have mixed up two rules.

One rule is

- If you implement a non-default constructor but no default constructor, the "compiler-generated" default constructor is implicitly deleted.
  If you want one you need to define it yourself. (In C++11, you can use `= default;`.)

(There are more situations that cause "special member functions" to be deleted, but this is the one most people stumble across first.)

The other rule ("the rule of three", which is more a rule of thumb) is

- If you need to implement a copy constructor, destructor, or assignment operator, you *probably* need to implement all three, so do it immediately.