# "attempting to reference a deleted function" for copy constructor

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, rule-of-three

I am trying to get my head around the Rule of 5.

I have a class `Renderable`, which defines a custom destructor, so it seemed like a good candidate for the Rule of 5. This class creates some resources in its constructor, so my first thought was that I should prevent copying:

```
class Renderable {

public:

    Renderable(const Sprite&) {
        // Allocate resources
    }

    ~Renderable() {
        // Free resources
    }

    // Prevent copying
    Renderable(const Renderable& other) = delete;

}
```

I have another class, `Unit`, which creates a `Renderable` in the initializer list of its constructor:

```
class Unit {

public:

    Unit(const Sprite& sprite) :
            renderable(Renderable(sprite)) {}

private:

    Renderable renderable;

}
```

I would expect this to call the regular `Renderable` constructor, but instead I get the error:

> Renderable::Renderable(const Renderable &)': attempting to reference a deleted function

**Why is this trying to call the copy constructor?**

I even tried added debug lines to the copy constructor, but nothing is printed:

```
Renderable(const Renderable& other) : sprite(other.sprite) {
    std::cout << "copy constructor";
}
```

Comment: Can we get a [mre]?

Comment: Because you explicitly called the copy constructor in a way that it can be elided, but only if it is not deleted...

Comment: @ChrisDodd guaranteed copy elision works even if the move and copy operators are deleted: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3b362cf2fe731f71

Comment: Wouldn't `Unit::Unit(const Sprite& sprite) : renderable(sprite) {}` work?

Comment: @NathanOliver: in that example you get a default move ctor, as there is no user-defined destructor (compared to the OP's code)

Comment: @ChrisDodd But deleting that move ctor doesn't matter: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/519597216ab37af9

Comment: @ChrisDodd No you don't.  deleting the copy constructor stops all move and the copy assignment from being generated.  see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3734247/what-are-all-the-member-functions-created-by-compiler-for-a-class-does-that-hap

Comment: Which C++ version are you using?

Comment: @TedLyngmo The default in VS 2017, which I believe is C++14.

Comment: If you manually select a C++ version to make sure which version you use, you can then add the version tag to your questions which makes it easier for people to help. The accepted solution obviously works in both C++14 and 17 (since it's avoiding the temporary in C++14), but the answer doesn't explain why you get a compilation error in C++14 while your original code would work fine in C++17 (as @NathanOliver has mentioned and proven in links to code).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to what others have said, I think you meant to write:

```
Unit::Unit(const Sprite& sprite) :
    renderable(sprite) {}
```

This invokes the converting constructor `Renderable(const Sprite&)` to initialise `renderable` directly, no copying involved.

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/qKxofesypHHkGCnq)

Comment: This is exactly right, thank you. I did not know that this would implicitly call the `Renderable` constructor.

Answer (score 4):

First, `Renderable(sprite)` creates a `Renderable`. Then you try to construct `renderable` with that `Renderable`. Conceptually, what could that use other than a copy constructor?

Why are you creating a `Renderable` to initialize `renderable`? That step is not needed and won't work because you have no copy constructor. You've specifically said that you don't want code that conceptually uses a copy constructor to work.

Comment: *What could that use other than a copy constructor?* C++17's guaranteed copy elision says the direct constructor: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b8874fa5edf90564

Comment: I guess I should clarify that I mean conceptually, not in actual execution.

Comment: Even conceptually.  You have a prvalue, which is not actually creating a temporary.

Comment: @NathanOliver probably they are using a pre-C++17 compiler

Comment: I thought it was necessary to call the constructor explicitly, to provide a value to `renderable`. You're absolutely right, though, that step is not needed.

Comment: @Dan The value you want to provide to `renderable`'s constructor is `sprite`. Since this is an initialization list, it's a given that you're constructing the object you're initializing.

Answer (score 1):

> Why is this trying to call the copy constructor?

Because

```
  renderable(Renderable(sprite)) {}
```

This constructs a temporary `Renderable` object, and then uses it to construct the `renderable` class members. That would be a

> I even tried added debug lines to the copy constructor, but nothing is
>   printed:

This is because this is one of the situations where compilers are permitted to do copy-elision. Even though the compiler optimizes away a temporary+copy construction, the constructor must still exist. Something about the class causes the default copy constructor to be deleted. There could be several reasons for that, but you did not provide sufficient information about your class in order to determine what that reason might be.

Comment: It's explicitly deleted: `Renderable(const Renderable& other) = delete;`

Comment: @TedLyngmo Doesn't matter in C++17: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3b362cf2fe731f71

Comment: @NathanOliver It was a comment on "_Something about the class causes the default copy constructor to be deleted._" but perhaps I misunderstood.

Comment: @TedLyngmo The copy constructor wasn't being deleted when I added the debug lines.

Comment: @Dan No, but then you didn't get the error about the deleted copy constructor either. The compiler figured out that it could actually elide the copying all together (which is why you didn't see your `"copy constructor"` message).