# C++ External Class in std::vector ( definition would be ill-formed )

Tags: c++

I have built a class in an external library that I was hoping to use in other areas.  However, when I try to use the class within an std::vector I get compile errors

```
                 from ../../src/geom/geom.cpp:21:
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/ext/new_allocator.h: In instantiation of `void __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::construct(_Up*, _Args&& ...) [with _Up = GenUtils::MeshNormalData; _Args = {const GenUtils::MeshNormalData&}; _Tp = GenUtils::MeshNormalData]`:
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/alloc_traits.h:254:4:   required from `static typename std::enable_if<std::allocator_traits<_Alloc>::__construct_helper<_Tp, _Args>::value, void>::type std::allocator_traits<_Alloc>::_S_construct(_Alloc&, _Tp*, _Args&& ...) [with _Tp = GenUtils::MeshNormalData; _Args = {const GenUtils::MeshNormalData&}; _Alloc = std::allocator<GenUtils::MeshNormalData>; typename std::enable_if<std::allocator_traits<_Alloc>::__construct_helper<_Tp, _Args>::value, void>::type = void]`
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/alloc_traits.h:393:57:   required from `static decltype (_S_construct(__a, __p, (forward<_Args>)(std::allocator_traits::construct::__args)...)) std::allocator_traits<_Alloc>::construct(_Alloc&, _Tp*, _Args&& ...) [with _Tp = GenUtils::MeshNormalData; _Args = {const GenUtils::MeshNormalData&}; _Alloc = std::allocator<GenUtils::MeshNormalData>; decltype (_S_construct(__a, __p, (forward<_Args>)(std::allocator_traits::construct::__args)...)) = <type error>]`
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_vector.h:906:34:   required from `void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back(const value_type&) [with _Tp = GenUtils::MeshNormalData; _Alloc = std::allocator<GenUtils::MeshNormalData>; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type = GenUtils::MeshNormalData]â€™
../../src/geom/geom.cpp:315:47:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/ext/new_allocator.h:120:4: error: use of deleted function `GenUtils::MeshNormalData::MeshNormalData(const GenUtils::MeshNormalData&)`
  { ::new((void *)__p) _Up(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }
    ^
In file included from ../../src/geom/geom.h:60:0,
                 from ../../src/geom/geom.cpp:21:
../../src/libs/utils/generalUtils.h:94:7: note: `GenUtils::MeshNormalData::MeshNormalData(const GenUtils::MeshNormalData&)` is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
 class MeshNormalData
```

in libs/generalUtils.h

```
namespace GenUtils
{
   class MeshNormalData
   {
   public:
      MeshNormalData(){}
   };
}
```

in geom.h

```
#include generalUtils.h

class TestGeo : public Base
{
public:
    TestGeo(){};
private:
    std::vector< GenUtils::MeshNormalData > meshnormals;
    void compute_geo();
};
```

in geom.cpp

```
void TestGeo::compute_geo()
{
    meshnormals.clear()
    GenUtils::MeshNormalData normals()
    //- doing other computation on normals
    meshnormals.push_back( normals );
}
```

What am I missing?  Any advice?  Need help deciphering my error.

Comment: It looks like you're missing the copy constructor of `MeshNormalData`, which was "implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed". Show us what `MeshNormalData` is. If `MeshNormalData` is non-copyable, but movable, try `meshnormals.push_back(std::move(normals));`.

Comment: Thanks added the copy constructor to my MeshNormalData and worked.

Comment: This is not a real testcase. e.g. `normals` is a function. Don't make us guess. Present a real [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key part of the error is where it says the definition of `MeshNormalData`'s copy constructor is deleted.

The error will be generated because something about the program requires the copy constructor to not be deleted: to be accessible and usable.

The copy is needed here:

```
meshnormals.push_back( normals );
```

because you do not write `std::move`.

You can get away with a non-copyable class in a vector if it's *moveable*. But you may wish to make your class copyable. Presumably in your real code there's [something about the type that prevents that](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4943958/5606480).

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the copy constructor for the class.
There is no problem with Vector as you mentioned in question title, its class MeshNormalData.
Push_back expect the copy constructor.

Below link can help you more:
[What are all the member-functions created by compiler for a class? Does that happen all the time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3734247/what-are-all-the-member-functions-created-by-compiler-for-a-class-does-that-hap)

Answer (score 0):

Added a copy constructor to make the it copyable.

```
namespace GenUtils
{
   class MeshNormalData
   {
   public:
      MeshNormalData(){}
      MeshNormalData( const MeshNormalData &obj){};    // copy 
   };
}
```

using `meshnormals.push_back(std::move(normals));` worked too.

Thanks Evg!

Comment: You put `MeshNormalData` inside `MeshNormalData`. Please take more care over your posts. It only takes a moment, and is a small courtesy to those giving you help for free at the weekend.

Comment: Sorry first time posting, fixed it.  Thank you for the help.