# derived pass to supper move constructor

Tags: c++

move derived obj `d` to  derived `dd`, but match `base`'s move constructor, do not match `derived`'s constructor

```
// base class 
class base {
    int x;

public:
    base() = default;

    base(base && b) {
        x = b.x;
    }
};

// derived struct
struct derived : public base {
    int y;

    derived(int d) {
        y = d;
    }

    derived() = default;
};

int main()
{
    derived d{1};
    derived dd = std::move(d);
    spdlog::info(dd.y); // => 1
    return 0;
}
```

I do not know why `dd.y` will be 1, not 0 ?

how `d.y` copied to `dd.y` struct ?

Comment: related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3734247/what-are-all-the-member-functions-created-by-compiler-for-a-class-does-that-hap

Comment: UB with copy/move of uninitialized `x`.

Comment: `the compiler will generate a copy constructor for you unless you declare your own.` -> thanks very much

Comment: And generated move constructor of derived will call move constructor of base.