# How does the copy constructor work in this code?

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

I have been reading Bruce Eckel's "Thinking in C++" and I came across the copy constructor. While I understand mostly the need for a copy-constructor, I am a bit confused about the following code below:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class foo  
{
    static int objCount;
public:
    foo()
    {
        objCount++;
        cout<<"constructor :"<<foo::objCount<<endl;
    }
    ~foo()
    {
        objCount--;
        cout<<"destructor :"<<foo::objCount<<endl;
    }

};

int foo::objCount=0;
int main()
{
    foo x;
    foo y = x;
    return 0;
}
```

In the above code, constructor is called once and destructor twice.
Here's what I don't understand:

1. `y` is an object of `class foo`, so why doesn't the compiler call the constructor and then copy the contents of `x` into `y`?
2. Where does the default copy-constructor provided by the compiler fit in this picture?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> y is an object of class foo, so why doesn't the compiler call the constructor and then copy the contents of x into y?

It does.

It calls the *copy* constructor, to do exactly that.

> Where does the default copy-constructor provided by the compiler fit in this picture?

You didn't provide your own copy constructor which produces any output, so the automatically-generated one (which doesn't) gets called.

The default constructor (the one that looks like `foo()`) doesn't get invoked at all during a copy. Only the copy constructor (the one that looks like `foo(const foo&)`).

Only *one* constructor happens per construction. Well, unless you're using delegating constructors, but we'll talk about that another day.

---

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class foo  
{
    static int objCount;
public:
    foo()
    {
        objCount++;
        cout<<"constructor :"<<foo::objCount<<endl;
    }
    foo(const foo&)
    {
        objCount++;
        cout<<"copy constructor :"<<foo::objCount<<endl;
    }
    ~foo()
    {
        objCount--;
        cout<<"destructor :"<<foo::objCount<<endl;
    }

};

int foo::objCount=0;

int main()
{
    foo x;
    foo y = x;
    return 0;
}

// constructor :1
// copy constructor :2
// destructor :1
// destructor :0
```

Answer (score 1):

> 1. y is an object of class foo, so why doesn't the compiler call the
>    constructor and then copy the contents of x into y?

In that case it calls not the constructor, but the copy constructor (which you didn't specified but compiler created it). Here you create a new object *y*, so it needs to be constructed (copy-constructed because you use other object *x*).

```
foo y = x;
```

> 2. Where does the default copy-constructor provided by the compiler fit
>    in this picture?

You can also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3734247/what-are-all-the-member-functions-created-by-compiler-for-a-class-does-that-hap) question. There's an explanation of other functions compiler creates implicitly. Sometimes it could be frustrating (especially when you work with raw pointers) so you should be aware of those functions.

Comment: The resource you shared regarding the implicit functions created by compiler is really helpful.Thank you!