# static assert on std::is_nothrow_move_constructible_v<class name> is not working

Tags: c++14, move, type-traits, static-assert, noexcept

```
class Base
{
public:
     Base(Base&&) = default;
};

class Derived: public Base
{    

public:
    Derived(Derived&&)  = default;

};

int main()
{
    static_assert(std::is_nothrow_move_constructible_v<Derived>, "Error noexcept");
}
```

In this code even if neither Derived nor Base declared move constructor `noexcept` but still this passes static assert on  `std::is_nothrow_move_constructible_v<Derived>`.
Why?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are all the member-functions created by compiler for a class? Does that happen all the time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3734247/what-are-all-the-member-functions-created-by-compiler-for-a-class-does-that-hap)

Comment: @MicroVirus No. I know all special member function provide/implemented by compiler but my question is different. Please see code example.

Comment: If you make `Base(Base&&) noexcept(false) = default;` at least `clang++` will refuse it. If you also make `Derived(Derived&&) noexcept(false) = default;` MSVC will also refuse it. `g++` accepts both :-)

Comment: @TedLyngmo  so If I did not  write noexcept in move constructor and ask compiler to provide `default`  implementation. It will always take noexcept(true)?

Comment: @gauravbharadwaj No, it depends on if the parent class too. [example](https://godbolt.org/z/G4KzKo3zK)